# How can my character earn money?

Tags: treasure, wealth, rolemaster

**Background**

We're running a custom campaign in rolemaster (RM) with rather unexperienced players and an experienced GM. We did about 6 or 7 sessions, the next one will be the third for my new character - and I am basically broke. In RM you roll on your wealth upon character creation, and I scored rather low (started out with 2 silver and a bit). Also, my character can't haggle (at all).

**The party**

There is a party treasure we pay equipment for the whole group from, but it's not overly filled. One of the other characters is rather wealthy, he has about 80 gold, but he is not overly willing to pay for the whole group. Currently we're in a city and doing some quests/bounty hunting. The prices either get shared or go to the party treasure.

**My goal**

I don't want to have to worry about how to pay for arrows, mead, food or the occasional wench - not to speak of luxury stuff like better armor.

**Question**

What options do I/we have to get more money? Ideally without stealing from other party members, rather by increasing the cash flow for the whole group.

Comment: Are you more interested in getting the whole party to that point of financial comfort, or are answers that prioritise getting your character to that point without bringing the other PCs up with you acceptable?

Comment: @LizWeir the party is secondary, since the other players have a distinct monetary advantage to me. Still, I would rather not betray them.

Comment: I think that this is a question you should ask your GM. How much or little money the PCs end up with is mostly up to how generous they are with treasure and quest rewards.

Comment: @Philipp I agree, but it could also be a mechanical issue: *Does the game have rules for making a living by practicing a nonadventuring profession?* Alternatively, it could be question about the game's expectations: *Does the game assume that PCs earn money solely through adventuring?* As it stands, I'm tempted to vote to close this question as an idea-generation one. (Note that I haven't voted to close it, though, as I'm familiar with *Rolemaster* only through nerd osmosis; maybe an expert can answer the question as it stands, explaining how the game directly addresses this situation.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rolemaster characters can have several abilities that could get you some quick money (hunting, foraging, leather working, singing and so on) besides the quest reward income system. If you don’t have any of these, maybe there is a chance you invest in one that fits your character next time you level up.

Besides that, a couple things come to mind.

**Talk to your GM:**

Explain that you want your character to be more financially stable and ask him/her for options. GMs generally like to know what their players want and might tailor the adventure to try to grant you your wishes.

**Talk to your group:**

In character: Guys, we are risking our lives here and we are barely scraping by, I understand some of you have more money and this is not a concern for you, but it is for me and I would like to pick quests/missions/tasks that are financially profitable

**Ask around:**

Whenever you walk into a town, ask if there are jobs to be done and money to be made. You might hear about some nobleman needing something done or a gladiator arena where champions are showered in gold.

**Everything is for sale:**

Attacked by wolves? Skin them. Attacked by orcs? Take their weapons and armor. Even if you do not haggle, someone in the group might and he/she could get you or the group better prices, he /she will get exp for it so it’s a win win.

**You do not want to steal from party members…**

But are you willing to steal from everybody else? I don’t know what sort of campaign you are in and it might not be viable, but at least keep it in mind.

Comment: Nice overview of options, thank you. We're doing some of this stuff already. Sadly our next session has (again) been postponed for an unknown time.